# Is there any notification mechanism for mobile application itself as APNS for mobile user?

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

My web/mobile applications use APNS, and it works without problem. In my understanding, APNS is to notify mobile users once there is new information for that user from my web server, like new friend request etc.

I have another use case. For example, the user modified some alarm clock setting at web application, the same alarm clock setting need to apply to mobile application for that user. How can I push this setting into mobile application without user triggering.

(for example, user indicated alarm at 7am and 8am at mobile application side, this information is synced to server side. Later when user indicated he needs another alarm at 9am from web application, how do I push this to mobile application so that user gets alarmed at 7am, 8am and 9am?)

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why not use local notifications?

Comment: Hi hypercrypt, yes we use local notification to activate the said alarm in the user's device. My question is how to sync the alarm setting from web server to mobile application if the setting is modified from web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a web service, then when your app launch, you can make 1 request to the server to ask for the server's version of the alarm.

Update your alarm on the local device to match.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can do that to sync the settings when the local device gets launched. What we are thinking now is to push apns notification with custom message to device whenever there is setting changed from server side. And at device side, the custom apns message will be parsed and used to update the setting locally.